# How can i do a textbox list using jquery having multiple tag in one textbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I have  a list of tags that are stored in the database. When a user starts a topic, he can enter the 3 tags, just like stackoverflow. I want to create a texbox list like how stackoverflow has done it.
th 
When the tag is new which is not stored in the database, i won't show the auto suggest but accept the tag. But when the tag is not new which is already in the database, i want to show the auto-suggest and when the user clicks the auto-suggest, the textbox is filled with the tag.

I want the tags to be separated by comma where when the user enter the comma, the tag is displayed in the textbox just like stackoverflow.

Anyone has any idea how can i do this? I tried researching in the net but there are scripts that need to be bought which i can't afford.

Do you have a better suggestion? I just need to enter multiple tags maximum 3 tags in the one textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) . It's hard to find a production ready scripts that can full-fill all your needs. This script can aid you al lot. The rest you need to modify/edit accordingly to your need.